# TypeError: unbound method getInterfaceName() must be called with Interface instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, typeerror

class Unit:
    def **init**(self, _chassisId, _unitNo, _interface):
        self.chassisId = _chassisId
        self.unitNo = _unitNo
        self.interface = _interface

```
def getInterface(self):
    return self.interface

@staticmethod
def parse(elem):
    unitList = elem.find(UNIT+LIST)
    chassisList = []
    for unit in unitList.findall(UNIT):
        try:
            unitNumber = unit.find(UNIT_NUMBER).text
            interface = unit.find(INTERFACE)
            interface = ""
            chassisIdElem = unit.find(CHASSIS_ID)
            chassisId = ""
            if chassisIdElem is not None:
                chassisId = unit.find(CHASSIS_ID).text
            elif unit.find(BURNED_IN_MAC) is not None:
                chassisId = unit.find(BURNED_IN_MAC).text
            chassisId = chassisId.replace(".", "").replace(":", "").upper()
            chassis = Unit(chassisId, interface, unitNumber)
            chassisList.append(chassis)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Unit details not found", e
        return chassisList

def getChassisId(self):
    return self.chassisId

def __str__(self):
    str = "\n"
    str += "\nUnit Details:- "
    len = str.__len__();
    str += "\n"
    for i in range(1,len-1):
        str += "-"
    str += "\nUnit: " + self.unitNo
    str += "\nChassis Id: " + self.chassisId
    str += "\nInterfaces: " + self.interfaces
    return str

def __add__(self, other):
    return str(self) + other

def __radd__(self, other):
    return other + str(self)
```

class Interface:
    def **init**(self, _linkState, _interfaceName):
        self.linkState = _linkState
        self.interfaceName = _interfaceName

```
@staticmethod
def parse(elem):
    prefix = Device.getPrefix(elem.tag)
    interfaceList = elem.find(INTERFACE + LIST)
    interfaceNameTag = eval(prefix + "_INTERFACE_NAME")
    linkStateTag = eval(prefix + "_LINK_STATE")
    interfaces = []
    for interface in interfaceList.findall(INTERFACE):
        try:
            interfaceName = interface.find(interfaceNameTag).text
            linkStateElem = interface.find(LINK_STATE)
            linkState = ""
            if linkStateElem is not None:
                linkState = interface.find(LINK_STATE).text
            elif interface.find(LINE_PROTOCOL) is not None:
                linkState = interface.find(LINE_PROTOCOL).text
            interface = Interface(linkState, Name)
            interfaces.append(interface)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Interface details not found", e
            return interfaces

def getLinkState(self):
    return self.linkState

def getInterfaceName(self):
    return self.interfaceName

def __str__(self):
    str = "\n"
    str += "\nInterface  Details:- "
    len = str.__len__();
    str += "\n"
    for i in range(1,len-1):
        str += "-"
    str += "\nLink State: " + self.linkState
    str += "\nInterface Name: " + self.interfaceName
    return str

def __add__(self, other):
    return str(self) + other

def __radd__(self, other):
    return other + str(self)
```

Comment: You are calling the getInterfaceName() directly and not as object method. Call it like Interface().getInterfaceName().

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us the call to `getInterfaceName()` that causes the error, which makes it harder to help you.

However, I'll guess that the call looks something like this:

```
something = Interface.getInterfaceName()
```

You can't do it that way.  You must create an *instance* of `Interface`, and then call its `.getInterfaceName()` method:

```
myInterface = Interface()
something = myInterface.getInterfaceName()
```